# Large-Signal Analysis of Diode-Connected MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I know that diode connected devices act as resistors in small-signal domain.

However, two diode connected devices can also be used to divide a large signal DC voltage based on the square-law equation. I understand that and I was just doing some analysis to see what the exact Vin-Vout relation is but I’ve gotten a bit lost:

[image]

Any ideas on how to proceed. I was hoping to get some nice relationship based on the ratios of the two FET sizes.